# my android device cannot connect to made wifi hotspot

Tags: wireless, android

first I created a wifi hot spot for android successfully.
Its being detected but cannot connect, its getting stuck at obtaining ip address. 
why?
please help.

Comment: my hotspot is being detected by the android  device,but it gets stuck at obtaining ip address

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android devices (some Android phones) cannot detect Ubuntu created ad-hoc wifi. For Android phones to detect wifi install ap-hotspot. It has no GUI, it runs on the command line.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ap-hotspot
```

- to configure

  ```
  sudo ap-hotspot configure
  ```
- to start

  ```
  sudo ap-hotspot start
  ```
- to stop

  ```
  sudo ap-hotspot stop
  ```

If you get problem connecting with the android devices then try the below steps,

The problem may be with the recent hostapd(bugs) version package that installs with ap-hotspot.

First uninstall ap-hotspot. Download old hostapd package(bug free) you can get it from

wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/w/wpa/hostapd_1.0-3ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb

To install hostpad.deb you can use gdebi package manager or simply from terminal

```
sudo dpkg -i hostapd_1.0-3ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb
```

After installation you need to hold the package so that it won't get updated to latest version, open your terminal

```
sudo apt-mark hold hostapd
```

Now install ap-hotspot normally.

Do not update the hostapd package.

Comment: which ones can/?

Comment: most androids are not advanced as ad-hoc provided by Ubuntu

Comment: thanks very much it worked,but i experience slow internet connection on phone

Comment: i did the same but still it is stuck on obtaining ip address

Comment: @NiteshVerma edited my answer see that you may find your solution.

Comment: [AP-Hotspot](https://github.com/hotice/AP-Hotspot) is no longer maintained. I was able to use [create_ap](https://github.com/oblique/create_ap) linked on the Ap-Hotspot GItHub page. It is working great on Debian Stretch.